# How to download a file from docker container running on EC2 instance to local machine?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ftp, sftp

To run our django application in production we need to build a docker image first and then run the django shell.
I have written a script to aggregate a bunch of data as per the product requirement(regarding the affected users due to a recent bug) into a csv file.
Now I need to download this file to my local machine. I can't find a way right now.

I created a download.sh file in our ec2 instance with the follwing content.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER_ID="<container_id>". # docker container id
FILE_PATH="<file_path_inside_container>"  # file path inside docker container 
OUTPUT_FILE="<output_file_name>"  # name of the downloaded file

docker cp $CONTAINER_ID:$FILE_PATH $OUTPUT_FILE
```

Then made the shell script executable by:
`chmod +x download_file.sh`

And then ran the shell script:
`./download_file.sh`

But this is unable to download the file as the file gets removed as soon as I exit the docker container.

I tried to find a way to copy the file from the docker container to the host on which it is running and then download it to my machine. But was unable to do so as well.

Comment: Can you write an admin endpoint in your application to directly download the data, without manually running commands and without using `docker cp`?  Or can you run the aggregation script on the host instead of in a container?  Or can it write its CSV output to stdout, so when you `docker run --rm ...` it you can `... >output.csv` to save the results?

Comment: It can be written to stdout